# Does 'argv' in python always use script name as the first argument?

Tags: python, macos, argv

Does 'argv' in python always use script name as the first argument? How can it be avoided?

For example, I'll call this sample.py:

```
from sys import argv

one, two, three = argv

print "My first number is ", one
print "My second number is ", two
print "My third number is ", three
```

When entered into the terminal

```
python sample.py one two three
```

It returns:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

And when entered into terminal:

```
python sample.py one two
```

It returns:

```
python seq1.py ONE TWO 
My first number is  seq1.py
My second number is  ONE
My third number is  TWO
```

- When running in the terminal, can you avoid the first variable always being assigned to script name?
- Is there a way to have input and use just the variables you want without the script name? Or even, in some way, "mute" the printing of a throw away line with the script name?

Comment: You can simply discard the first element in when unpacking with `_, one, two, three = argv` . (the underscore is convention for "don't care about this", basically)

Comment: Yes, Python always use script name as the very first element of `argv` list See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv)

Answer (score 3):

you can do

```
argv[1:]
```

to have a list of arguments without the filename.

What this does is slicing the argv list and returning a new one without the first element. You can read more about list slicing [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)

Here's an example

```
from sys import argv

one, two, three = argv[1:]

print "My first number is ", one
print "My second number is ", two
print "My third number is ", three
```